# Importing from subdirectory into subdirectory

Tags: python, import

1. How do I import from b1.py into b2.py
2. How do I import from sa1 into b2?

```
test/                      # root folder
    packA/                 
        subA/              
            __init__.py
            sa1.py
            sa2.py
        __init__.py
        a1.py
        a2.py
    packB/                 
        b1.py
        b2.py
    math.py
    random.py
    other.py
    start.py
```

EDIT
solved it by putting:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
```

where os.getcwd() is the project's root directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `from packB import b1`
2. `from packA.subA import sa1`

Comment: that's what I tried, David, but I get "no module defined: packB" for the first case.

Comment: `packB` must be in your PYTHONPATH (e.g. export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/test/packB"). Is that the case?

Comment: I haven't dealt with PYTHONPATH perhaps that is the problem. I will look it up.

Comment: It looks like i solved the issue by appending sys.path. However, either way PYTHONPATH or sys.path are both kind of clunky, especially given that they are in one project. Do you know if that's the regular approach?

Comment: There are alternatives; you can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55656738) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1893622).